# Efficiently Store List of Numbers in Binary Format

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, binary, compression, storage

I'm writing a compression algorithm (mostly for fun) in C, and I need to be able to store a list of numbers in binary. Each element of this list will be in the form of two digits, both under 10 (like `(5,5), (3,6), (9,2)`). I'll potentially be storing thousands of these pairs (one pair is made for each character in a string in my compression algorithm).

Obviously the simplest way to do this would be to concatenate each pair (-> `55, 36, 92`) to make a 2-digit number (since they're just one digit each), then store each pair as a 7-bit number (since 99 is the highest). Unfortunately, this isn't so space-efficient (7 bits per pair).

Then I thought perhaps if I concatenate each pair, then concatenate that (`553692`), I'd be able to then store that as a plain number in binary form (`10000111001011011100`, which for three pairs is already smaller than storing each number separately), and keep a quantifier for the number of bits used for the binary number. The only problem is, this approach requires a bigint library and could be potentially slow because of that. As the number gets bigger and bigger (+2 digits per character in the string) the memory usage and slowdown would get bigger and bigger as well.

So here's my question: Is there a better storage-efficient way to store a list of numbers like I'm doing, or should I just go with the bignum or 7-bit approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information-theoretic minimum for storing 100 different values is `log2100`, which is about 6.644. In other words, the possible compression from 7 bits is a hair more than 5%. (`log2100 / 7` is 94.91%.)

If these pairs are simply for temporary storage during the algorithm, then it's almost certainly not worth going to a lot of effort to save 5% of storage, even if you managed to do that.

If the pairs form part of you compressed output, then your compression cannot be great (a character is only eight bits, and presumably the pairs are additional to any compressed character data.) Nonetheless, the easy compression technique is to store up to 6 pairs in 40 bits (5 bytes), which can be done without a bigint package assuming a 64-bit machine. (Alternatively, store up to 3 pairs in 20 bits and then pack two 20-bit sequences into five bytes.) That gives you 99.66% of the maximum compression for the values.

All of the above assumes that the 100 possible values are equally distributed. If the distribution is not even and it is possible to predict the frequencies, then you can use Hoffman encoding to improve compression. Even so, I wouldn't recommend it for temporary storage.

Comment: So in other words, use the base idea behind bigint, but instead of using one bigint, clip it up into multiple numbers?

Comment: @CalebP: It's no different from observing that two digits can be combined algebraically into a two-digit number. Six digits can be combined into a six-digit number. All the same, it is only a few percent of compression, and its unlikely to be worth the effort IMHO.